# Comic story where woman becomes God

Tags: story-identification, comics

I had a comic from probably the early 90’s that I have no idea how to track down. It was a short story where a woman created a computer program with virtual creatures who ended up worshipping her like a god. Eventually they stopped believing in her and she disintegrated. It didn’t have anything to do with the main title of course, just a little ~6 page one-off. Does anyone remember reading a comic book with this story and might be able to find out which title it was?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any idea what the main title would have been?  Can you describe the artwork at all, even if it was in colour vs. black-and-white?

Comment: I have no recollection of what the main title could have been. It could have been DC or Marvel. It was definitely in color though.